# Django admin form extra field

Tags: django-forms, django-admin

I want to add an extra field (column) that is not in the model. So, I created a model form in which the new extra field is defined.

**admin.py**

```
class WorkingHourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = WorkingHour
        fields = ['day', 'period', 'time_range', 'extra_field']

class WorkingHourInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = WorkingHour
    form = WorkingHourForm
```

This should work because it's pretty much a copy of an example in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelforms-overriding-default-fields). 
However, this raises the error: Unable to lookup 'extra_field' on WorkingHour or WorkingHourInline

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
class WorkingHourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field = forms.CharField(label='extra_field', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = WorkingHour
        fields = ['day', 'period', 'time_range', 'extra_field']

class WorkingHourInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = WorkingHour
    form = WorkingHourForm
```

Adding label='extra_field' solved this for me in a similar use of tabularinline.. I think the django admin example works as is but when used in conjunction with the admin.TabularInline, it does not. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

remove `extra_field` from `fields = ['day', 'period', 'time_range', 'extra_field']`. If you do like that django will tries to get value for the `extra_field` from model. so, it will raises an error.

After modification, Above code will look like

```
class WorkingHourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = WorkingHour
        fields = ['day', 'period', 'time_range']

class WorkingHourInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = WorkingHour
    form = WorkingHourForm
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. But, the same error still occurs. But why do I need to remove `extra_field` from `fields` when the example in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelforms-overriding-default-fields) that I link to has `slug` which is not in the model either?

Comment: have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your form's Meta:

```
labels = {"extra_field": "blah"}
```